# cifs fails to mount windows server share: Duplicate cookie detected

Tags: windows, samba, fstab, cifs

I'm trying to mount windows share, here is my /etc/fstab:

```
//X.Y.Z.W/share3 /media/share3  cifs  username=User,password=MyPass12345,vers=1.0,iocharset=utf8,noperm 0  0
```

Here is what I get as error from dmesg:

```
[590293.906036] CIFS: Attempting to mount //X.Y.Z.W/share3
[590293.907991] FS-Cache: Duplicate cookie detected
[590293.908801] FS-Cache: O-cookie c=00000000176e1b73 [p=0000000000598190 fl=222 nc=1 na=1]
[590293.909561] FS-Cache: O-cookie d=00000000fd22912a n=000000001de84815
[590293.910299] FS-Cache: O-key=[8] '020001bd9200e3d6'
[590293.911033] FS-Cache: N-cookie c=00000000876aef61 [p=0000000000598190 fl=2 nc=0 na=1]
[590293.911789] FS-Cache: N-cookie d=00000000fd22912a n=0000000018b3dc61
[590293.912554] FS-Cache: N-key=[8] '020001bd9200e3d6'
[590293.918838] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
```

Removing vers=1.0 doesn't help, but gives different error.

On Windows 10 it mounts correctly with the same share:

```
net use b: \\X.Y.Z.W\share3 /user:User MyPass12345
```

How can I solve this?

UPD: finally somehow mounted after system restart without vers=... sucessfully.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use vers=3.0

I also have "FS-Cache: Duplicate cookie detected" errors, but I can mount shares. I think it is another problem not related to "mount fail".